# angular filtering decode characters

Tags: filter, angularjs, decode

in angular, if

```
$scope.myStr = '&trade;';
```

{{myStr}} yields '$trade;' instead of the TM mark, how would I solve this issue using a filter?

and in some cases, $amp;trade; also appears, so I would absolutely need a filter to run the procedures, and eventually I want to be able to {{}} the result without dom manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngBindUnsafeHtml`: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnp3J/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="x">
    <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="myStr"></span>
</div>
```

-

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.myStr = '&trade;';
}
```

Comment: is that doable via {{ }} binding? b/c I need to be able to do that for other people to use my code.

Comment: i don't believe so -- see Misko's answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/jTLPiIxgIbg ; TLDR: you need an element to set .innerHTML on.

Comment: thanks, you are right on time to delivery answers that can lead me to apply other methods.